# IndexOutofBound error while deleting item from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have searched almost every possible question related to this topic but not able to resolve this issue. Whenever I try to delete items via custom delete button embedded with ListView item, after deleting few items it gives me error of IndexOutOfBound error. I know this error is coming due to list being not able to refresh itself after item has been removed with position. Here is my code:

```
MainActivity:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,getModel());
            //adapter.clear();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        list.add(get("Linux"));
        list.add(get("Windows7"));
        list.add(get("Suse"));
        list.add(get("Eclipse"));
        list.add(get("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(get("Solaris"));
        list.add(get("Android"));
        list.add(get("iPhone"));
        // Initially select one of the items
        //list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
      }

    private Model get(String s)
    {
        return new Model(s);
    }

}
```

Code for InteractiveArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;
    private ListView lv;
    private MainActivity ma;


    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        protected TextView text;
        protected Button btn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);


            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            viewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                        list.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();  

                }

            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.btn.setTag(list.get(position));
        } //when convertView = null
        else 
        {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).btn.setTag(list.get(position));
            //((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).text.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        //holder.btn.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Model getItem(int position) {
        return (null==list)? null: list.get(position);
    }


}
```

Code for Model Class:

```
public class Model 
{
    private String name;

    public Model(String name) {
    this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Any help regarding this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the following line

```
    //((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).text.setTag(list.get(position));
```

Replace your remove statement with the following one.

```
    list.remove(viewHolder.btn.getTag());
```

Comment: It almost worked but deleting item get stop when there are 3 items left in list...what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: In fact it is deleting in a very random order..another item get deleted on click other item..weird..

Comment: All I need to do was replace this "list.remove(position);" with your line "list.remove(viewHolder.btn.getTag());"..you are life saver..Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

as fare as i read this, you are inflating your view with a final position to be used in the OnClickListener

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

now you change your List by removing some Items, although your list ist also declared final it can be changed because it us mutable

```
private final List<Model> list;
```

so your List is changing and your position is pointing to somewhere outside the List after enough deletes

```
pseudocode
(1,2,3,4,5,6) with position = 4
delete(6)
delete(1)
delete(2)
results in (2,4,5)
now position 4 is pointing somewhere outside
```

Comment: Yes, You are right. But somewhat I am not able to figure it out through code.

Comment: Maybe you can switch to a HashMap<String,Model> and pass the String to the Listener so it will remove the correct entry. Then finished you can iterate over the keys left in the Map to do your further logic.

Answer (score 0):

change your adapter with  following code

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

  private final List<Model> list;
  private final Activity context; 
  private MainActivity ma;

 LayoutInflater inflator;
  public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list)
  {
    super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
    this.context = context;
    inflator =  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
  }

  static class ViewHolder
  {
    protected TextView text;
    protected Button btn;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {    
      convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
      viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

      viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
      viewHolder.btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);     
      convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
      }

    else 
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
     }
    viewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {       
            list.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  

            }

      });

   viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
   return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount()
  {
      return list.size();
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return list.get(position);
  }
```

Comment: you need to take look at how to create custom adapter for listview.